# Try_files not working with If block and causing 404 error

Tags: nginx-config

I serve a location with the following directive:

```
 try_files $request_uri $request_uri/index.html =404;
```

And if I add an add_header with the if block as below, I get a 404 error if the request_uri will match, if I remove this block or if the request_uri does not match, it works.  Even if I remove add_header, and if the url matches the condition, I get 404.

```
if ($request_uri = '/jp/%e8%a9%90%e6%ac%ba%e5%b8/' ) {
   add_header X-Header-Custom "test";
}
```

By the way, if the URL is not Unicode, I mean if it is something like /jp/example/, the same config works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of if block, using map solved the problem.

```
map $request_uri $my_val {
   '/jp/%e8%a9%90%e6%ac%ba%e5%b8/' 'test'; 
   default "";
}

add_header X-Header-Custom $my_val;
```